# How would eclipses change (both solar and lunar) if the moon was half the distance from the Earth?

Tags: moons, tides, eclipses

I'm working on building a fantasy world where the moon is in a lower orbit. I've already worked out the effect on tides; 4x stronger high tides slightly further apart, increased coastal erosion, more coastal towns like Le Mont St Michel isolated at high tide. I've also calculated that the orbital period of the moon would be 9.64 days meaning shorter "months". But I'm struggling to work out how regularly eclipses would occur and how they would be different.

If the moon was closer, the Earth's wobble would decrease, would this along with the increased size of the moon in comparison to the Earth and Sun mean there is a lunar eclipse every full moon and a solar eclipse every new moon?

I believe a total lunar eclipse would leave a ring of the moon visible around the shadow of the earth and a solar eclipse would be complete darkness with no corona visible, is this correct? How long would each last?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the moon stays the same size:

Total Solar eclipse before:
[image]

Total Solar eclipse after:
[image]

Pardon my lack of photoshop, those edges should be blurred.

There will be more solar eclipses - considerably more. The moon takes up about 3.5 more area of the sky, and moves about ~3 times as fast. Back of envelope astronomy says we'll go from 1-2 partial solar eclipses per year on average to about 20, and 0-1 total solar eclipses per year to about 8.

Eclipses will be ~3 times faster. On Earth, Temuco in Chile will get a [2:50 hour solar eclipse, 28 seconds will be total](https://www.timeanddate.com/eclipse/in/chile/temuco?iso=20201214) on 14 Dec 2020. On your planet, the eclipse will be about 55 minutes, about 55 seconds total (it's moving ~3 times faster, but is twice the size so starts a little sooner, and ends a little later).

Lunar eclipses will become more often. My home town of Adelaide will get a 5 hour total lunar eclipse on 26 May 2021. If the moon is ~3.5 times the size, and moving ~3 times as fast, the moon wont fully enter the Umbra, only 2/3rds will, the rest will only enter the Penumbra.

[image]

Comment: You beat me to answering, and with a better answer than mine was going to be. One question though: Since the moon is the same size but the umbra of the earth is larger at the moon's new distance, doesn't that mean total lunar eclipses will occur more often?

Comment: The diagram is exaggerated, those lines are very close to parallel. The moon currently can fit entirely between the umbra and penumbra, but make the moon bigger and its an extremely tight fit. I'll add a diagram.

Comment: The moon in this question isn't bigger, it's just closer to earth. That means it will fit in the umbra more easily.

Comment: Closer to earth will make it take up more of the sky, which I've simplified down to "bigger". You're right, it wont get more mass, but the angular diameter will approximately double if the object is bought to half the distance. Change in sky surface area will go up about 3.5 times.

Comment: I agree, the moon will appear bigger to an observer on earth, and this will have a significant impact on solar eclipses. However, length of a lunar eclipse is dependent on the opposite: How big does the earth appear to someone on the moon? The bigger earth appears, the bigger earth's umbra at that distance. It may only be different by a small amount due to the difference in earth/moon distance vs earth/sun distance, but the umbra will still be slightly bigger. Combine this with the moon's newly increased speed and you should be getting total lunar eclipses *more* often than before.

Comment: Sadly, noone will see these megaeclipses, as the closer moon would not have allowed life in the way we know it - tides would also be much more rampant...

Comment: The umbra will go from ~9000km at moon distance to about ~10700km at the new one (12740km umbra at earth centroid. 9000km at current moon, linear interpolation ~10700), which from the point of view of earth will be about at 15% increase in diameter. The moon about doubles in diameter.

Comment: The moon **does not** about doubles in diameter. It has the same diameter. And the umbra of Earth is **bigger** closer to Earth. I have no idea why you consider the angular diameter of the Moon, **but not** also the angular diameter of the relevant section of the umbra. Either work with the real diameters of both the Moon and the umbra, or else work with the angular diameters of both the Moon and the section of the umbra. Minus one for failing geometry.

Comment: @ AlexP No need to get rude - If I move something twice as close to me - it's going to appear larger in the 2D projection of the sky. It's basic trig, half the denominator into arctan, keep the numerator the same, angular diameter increases (it's about double 0.5 to 0.9). The umbra at that distance will also appear larger - same thing, the relevant angular diameter is about 15% larger. You're trying to fit a peg twice the size into a hole 15% larger - it's going to occur less. I'm going to delete that section of my answer cause it's not important. Feel free to put a better answer in.

Comment: Yes, if you move something closer to you it's going to appear twice as large. This holds **both** for the Moon **and** for the section of Earth's umbra crossed by the Moon's orbit. They will **both** appear twice as large. (Actually the section of the Earth's umbra will have a diameter **more** than twice as large, because the umbra is conical and it is actually larger at the closer distance.) Do you want me to draw a picture?

Comment: OK, [here is a picture](https://www.flickr.com/photos/alexpanoiu/50357220321).